# When is electrostatic force constant?

Tags: forces, electrostatics, work

I'm going through some of my Physics notes and I have this written:
$W = \Delta E_p = E_{p_f} - E_{p_i} = F_e \cdot d $

And I have written that $E_{p_i} = 0$.  And I've written in the margin "When is this valid?" pointing to the $= F_e \cdot d$ part of the above equation.  I believe this requires $F_e$ to be constant in magnitude and in the same direction as the displacement.  But I don't think I know in what situations $F_e$ would be constant vs when it would not be constant?

Comment: Be *very* careful with your symbols. The work done is the scalar product of the force and the displacement, *not* the vector product as you've unfortunately written.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited it to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

(a) Presumably $E_{p_i}$ and $E_{p_f}$ are initial and final potential energies as a particle's position in space changes from $p_i$ to $p_f$. Putting $E_{p_i}=0$ enacts a decision to choose $p_i$ as the point where the potential energy is zero.

(b) You could calculate the difference in potential energies from the work done on the particle by an external force pushing the particle from $p_i$ to $p_f$. So
$$p_f-p_i=\int_\mathbf{s_i}^\mathbf{s_f}\mathbf{F_e}.d\mathbf{s}$$
The integration allows for the likely changing value along the path from $p_i$ to $p_f$ of $\mathbf F_e$, which needs to be equal and opposite to the force on the particle due to the field.

Your version of the equation assumes that the force doesn't vary as we go from $p_i$ to $p_f$. This would be the case in a uniform field, such as the Earth's gravitational field *near the Earth's surface* or the electric field between the plates of a parallel plate capacitor (but not near to the edges of the plates).